# Correct terminology for result echoed when function printed in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, terminology

I know this is probably somewhere in the docs, but it's a bit hard to reverse search. When we explicitly `print` a function (not call it), what is the name of the echoed result?

eg.

```
def func():
    pass

print(func)
```

Returns:

```
<function func at 0x7f5f539587b8>
```

What is this result called? Another example would be `<class '__main__.a'>`.

Special kudos to the kind person who can tell me if these results can be used for something too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the "string representation" of the object. It is basically the best way that Python can figure out to represent your object with a string.

In the first case, Python was telling you, to paraphrase, "this is a function with name 'func' at memory location 0x7f5f539587b8". That's the best string representation it can give you without you giving it a better representation.

In the second case Python was telling you, "This is a class named 'a' and it is in the '**main**' module's name-space.

You can modify this value by defining the __repr__ special method of your class. __repr__ gives the "formal representation" and __str__ the "informal representation". See [this](http://pythoncentral.io/what-is-the-difference-between-__str__-and-__repr__-in-python/) for more details.

This, for example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, unique_name):
        self.unique_name = unique_name

    def __repr__(self):
        return "object of type A and name %s in the name-space of %s" \
               % (self.unique_name, __name__)

a = A('foo')
print(a)

class B:
    pass

b = B()
print(b)
```

returns:

```
object of type A and name foo in the name-space of __main__
<__main__.B object at 0x7ffb9eb37668>
```